# Axiomatically proving a subset of a set is a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In Jech & Hrbacek, the first few axioms introduced do not explicitly include that any subset of any set is itself a set. Thus, it must be provable from the basic axioms it does provide. I figure the only way to do this is using the separation schema axiom(s):

Let $S$ be a set and let $C\subseteq S$. Then by the axiom schema of separation, there exists a set $P = \{x\in S\, | \, x\in C\}$.

Is it that simple? The only reason I even bother is because in a prior book I used, it listed this as an axiom in its own right.

Comment: Actually no axiom is needed to show that a subset of a set is a set; if it weren't a set it wouldn't be a subset :P It's Separation that ensures that there exist subsets defined by specific properties.

Comment: Thank you! I suppose I "see" what you mean, although the answer is a bit unsatisfying in the "rigorous" sense. I guess I was overthinking it after all!

Comment: It does sound unsatisfying as I put it, but it can be made perfectly rigorous; the translation of the statement, $\forall A\forall C(C\subseteq A\Rightarrow \exists D(x\in D\Leftrightarrow x\in C))$, is actually just a logical truth. I phrased it as I did because it's a trivial statement in a sense; but really, it's not always easy to see why it's trivial when one is first encountering set theory.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine: To see that it is indeed a meaningful question, you just have to formulate it differently: A *subclass* of a set is a set. And yes, separation is what guarantees it.

Comment: @celtschk - The intuitive question was not lost on me, but I wanted to highlight the difference between the intuitive question, and the actual question as stated, in order to tease out why one wants to look at the separation schema rather than some other single axiom that says that "subsets are sets".

Comment: And also to point out that absolutely no schema is needed to guarantee $\{x\in S\;|\; x\in C\}$ exists given the assumption $C\subseteq S$.

Comment: If we go with the above response (which I what I intended) and rephrase the question as: Is every subclass of a set a set? Then does the following suffice?

Let $S$ be an arbitrary set and let $C$ be a subclass of $S$. Then by the separation schema axioms, the set $C_0 = \{x\in S \, | \, x\in C\}$ exists. Hence, $C_0$ is a set that is equal to $C$ by extensionality.

I suppose by phrasing it as I did before, it makes little "sense," as all of the objects of axiomatic set theory are, indeed, sets. Thus if we introduce a subset of a set, it must be a set, by hypothesis.

Comment: Now that I think more about it, perhaps I'm "moving in the wrong direction" with this question. Subsets are defined upon bringing up the power set axiom, which constructs sets of subsets from currently existing sets. Thus, considering whether subclasses (that "come out of nowhere") of preexisting sets are sets themselves seems a little unneeded, as any time a set is defined, constructed, or assumed to exist, all its subsets are necessarily elements (hence, sets) of its power set.

Comment: Careful! The power set says that all the subsets of $S$ that there are are contained some set; but power set is not sufficient to guarantee that subsets with any specific property exist. Put another way, given a set $X$, how do you show that its power set contains anything but $X$ and $\varnothing$ (assuming the existence of the empty set is given)? The answer is still separation.

Comment: Indeed, the following is a model for extensionality + power set (+ union + regularity) with no proper subsets: Sets are elements of $\mathbb Z$ and $m\in n\iff m+1=n$. Every “set” is completely specified by its “elements” (that is, by its predecessor), each set is its only subset (there's no empty set in that model), the power set is the successor, and the union is the predecessor. Regularity is fulfilled because the only “element” does not have itself as “element”. Quite obviously separation doesn't hold in that model.

Comment: Yeah, what you guys seem to be saying sounds deeper than what I’m alluding to. All I’m concerned about is some set, say $S$, being introduced, whence from the statement “Let $C \subseteq S$“ may arise. Regardless of what properties $C$ possesses, since it has been given to be a subset of $S$, by hypotheses, it must be contained in the power set of $S$, and hence, a set itself (as all members of sets are themselves sets). In other words, I’m more concerned as to the “where” subsets come from and how they are justified as being sets, rather than abstract ‘ground-up’ constructions.